# How to insert complex code using DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, dom

I am still learning javascript.

Here is the site I am playing with. http://keysoft.keydesign-themes.com/demo1/

I want to insert google visualization chart code using DOM manipulation (insertAdjacentHTML) into this site.

Here is the code of google's timeline chart:

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
        dataTable.addRows([
          [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
          [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
          [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);

        chart.draw(dataTable);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
       <div id="timeline" style="height: 180px;"></div>
```

I tried the code below in Chrome's console in order to insert it into this site but I think there are a lot of mistakes. Could you help me please how to improve the code below?

```
document.getElementsByClassName('container')[5].getElementsByClassName('row')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
       <div id="timeline" style="height: 180px;"></div>

      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
        dataTable.addRows([
          [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
          [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
          [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);

        chart.draw(dataTable);
      }');
```

Comment: Um. Javascript inside html? Why do you think that will work?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn this into a string literal by using back ticks (`) instead of single quotes. And to ensure it doesn't jam up on the script tags you will want to change the closing script tag inside the literal to

```
<\/script>
```

I don't know the rest of your HTML structure so there may also be some issues with selecting the elements you want to place the tag inside.

Here's a complete example of a simple page that works for me:

```
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" class='container'>
        <div class="row"></div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>'use strict';
        document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].getElementsByClassName('row')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"><\/script>
              <div id="timeline" style="height: 180px;"></div>\n\n      <script> google.charts.load(\'current\', {\'packages\':[\'timeline\']});
              google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
               function drawChart() {
                   var container = document.getElementById(\'timeline\');
                   var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
                    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    dataTable.addColumn({ type: \'string\', id: \'President\' });
                    dataTable.addColumn({ type: \'date\', id: \'Start\' });
                    dataTable.addColumn({ type: \'date\', id: \'End\' });
                    dataTable.addRows([
                         [ \'Washington\', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
                         [ \'Adams\',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
                         [ \'Jefferson\',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);
                         chart.draw(dataTable);
                         }<\/script>`);
    </script>
```

I changed the number of containers from 5 to 0 for simplicity's sake but in the browser this runs without issue and injects the JS code after the row element. The back ticks (`) are important .

Comment: I have implemented your advice but now when I use it in Google Tag Manager I get "Use --language_in=ECMASCRIPT6 or ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT or higher to enable ES6 features.". 
So I have rewritten the code using es6console.com to this https://jsfiddle.net/gustavjung/5xdwjqgq 
But now GTM says 
1. Error at line 2, character 113: Parse error. Unterminated string literal
2. Error at line 2, character 297: Parse error. Invalid escape sequence
Is there a way to rewrite it?